# TypeScript toSafeArray: type a function that converts anything into an valid array

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

How do I type a function that turns *anything* into a safe array?

```js
toArray(null) // []: []
toArray(undefined) // []: []
toArray([]) // []: []
toArray({}) // [{}]: {}[]
toArray(0) // [0]: number[]
toArray('') // ['']: string[]
toArray(['']) // ['']: string[]
toArray([1]) // [1]: number[]
```

I currently have:

```js
function toArray<T>(
  value: T
): T extends null | undefined ? [] : T extends Array<infer U> ? U[] : [T] {
  if (value == null) {
    // It's invalid, return an empty array.
    const safeArray: [] = []
    return safeArray
  }

  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    // It's already an array, return it unmodified.
    const safeArray: T[] = value
    return safeArray
  }

  // It's valid, but not an array, turn it into an array.
  const safeArray: [T] = [value]
  return safeArray
}
```

But anything I return, TypeScript yells at me saying it's not assignable to the return type.

Previously I had:

```js
declare function toArray<T>(value: T | Array<T>): Array<T>
```

But it wrongly returns `null[]` and `undefined[]` which is undesired.

Comment: "TypeScript yells at me saying it's not assignable to the return type".  Where is such "yelling" happening?  Could you post a [mre] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (click this)](https://tsplay.dev/mx65bw) which clearly demonstrates the issue you're facing?  I am guessing the problem is happening within the implementation and this is an instance of [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) and you'll just need to use a type assertion and move on.  But that's just a guess until I see a genuine reproduction.

Comment: @jcalz Sure thing! There ya go: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcHsEECdYIYE8AqSAOBTAJqAzgBaQCuANrggMaWbrigIB2S4BAlowOYOO6ybhisRg3wIAZpgbxkAOgBQ88cUaVwbSCKhxEqDDgA8KAHwAKeaFAA3BKWKYAXKBTyAlE5ShMAD3CZeeKCMZKSgAD6gKtiY4hw4oAD8oADaALqgHl6+-tiBOsgGHJKwoACqxollaRkpKOkA3hagbOKgpjZ2UgC8XUEhrqCNlpYgoACS4ADkgRwdbNgANKD8gsI8XgC2dEjSugrDoJSaePR4Epj5SE7VvWlNlitCImeSl00AvoqWLW2Xsmx4S7tWz2VwDIbDUYTaYMUj8BDYHZMXbIJaPNZsegqDaQbAtNg4fbDI6ME5iV4yK7OG7WEGYe7LARPckXSkfL6gKFTQJzRagABGxHojEg9GRCEpS1WIkxzUYUHWEr2TRJZJerN01zqoFuHXsqSa6Oe5ze7yAA)

Comment: Thanks.  Please put that in plaintext in the question as well.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question as asked, but is there a reason you're returning `U[]` instead of just `T` when the value passed in is itself an array?  And you probably want to check `ReadonlyArray<any>` (or `infer U` I guess) instead of just `Array`, unless you want `toArray([1, 2, 3] as const)` to return a nested array type

Comment: Because ts was telling me `'U' is defined but never used`, so I used it, no other real reason.

Comment: But you can do `Array<any>` instead of `Array<infer U>` and it should work the same

Comment: Alright, changed it but still doesn't compile, does it have any relation to the issue you mentioned?

Comment: Yeah, it's a side issue (but one you might end up caring about, such as `toArray(null)` returns type `[]` but `toArray(toArray(null))` returns `never[]`, which is weird, right?).

Comment: By the way, I'm writing up an answer, but it might be a little while before I can post it.  (In case you were wondering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a design limitation or missing feature of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for an authoritative discussion.

The TypeScript compiler is not really able to perform much reasoning about [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on as-yet unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  Such types are essentially opaque to the compiler, and it cannot verify that a particular value is assignable to it.

When you *call* `toArray()`, the type parameter `T` is specified as some specific type (usually this is inferred by the compiler) and then the return type `T extends null | undefined ? [] : ...` can be evaluated to some specific type itself.  But in the *body* of `toArray()`, the type parameter `T` is not specified.  And so `T extends null | undefined ? [] : ...` is just some "black box" type.  You can check that `value` is `null`, but this does not narrow or specify the type parameter `T`, and so the compiler has no way to know if the value `[]` is assignable to `T extends null | undefined ? [] : ...`.  And you get compiler errors at each `return` statement:

```
function toArray<T>(
  value: T
): T extends null | undefined ? [] : T extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? T : [T] {
  if (value == null) { return []; } // error!
  if (Array.isArray(value)) { return value; } // error!
  return [value]; // error!
}
```

---

Until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#33912 is addressed, the only viable approach for such generic conditional types is to accept that the compiler is unable to verify that the implementation satisfies the call signature, and take the responsibility for such verification yourself.  One way to do that is with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) at each place where the compiler cannot verify assignability:

```
type ToArray<T> =
  T extends null | undefined ? [] :
  T extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? T :
  [T];

function toArray<T>(
  value: T
): ToArray<T> {
  if (value == null) { return [] as ToArray<T>; }
  if (Array.isArray(value)) { return value as ToArray<T>; }
  return [value] as ToArray<T>;
}
```

Now there are no errors.  Note that you need to make sure you do the right thing; you could change `value == null` to `value != null` and still there would be no errors.  The compiler is trusting you when you say `as ToArray<T>`, so make sure not to lie to it.

Anyway, that works but is tedious.  I made a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) of `ToArray<T>` to prevent writing out that long type every time, or giving up and writing `as any`.  In cases like this, I tend to not use type assertions and opt for single-call-signature [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) instead:

```
// call signature
function toArray<T>(
  value: T
): T extends null | undefined ? [] : T extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? T : [T];

// implementation
function toArray(value: unknown) {
  if (value == null) { return []; }
  if (Array.isArray(value)) { return value; }
  return [value];
}
```

Function overload implementations are checked more loosely than those of regular functions.  So the above compiles with no error.  Callers see only the one call signature, while the implementation is allowed to be looser and return a value of type `unknown`.  This is just as unsafe as type assertions (again, `!= null` would not be caught), but the implementation is cleaner and there's a clearer separation between the typing as seen by callers and that seen by the implementation.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5A9jKSDeAoXSSAZgK7DwAuAlmsEhWgIIBOzIAngDwAqAfABQFCSAG4gANiQgAuJNyEBKWdyQQAHhQjAAJlmAlx4pAB8kZbRCJVgEbUgD8SANoBdJMtUatupACUIINq04uwsbFwgwOy8DnLuztxueMJIVERI-GKSyAC8OUj6hgo4SMwQFCTMdK4A3EgAvkgA9E2qrGjMAIRChGkZYRwAdFRQA+yZElIKxdil5ZV0WVJ1jS1tzB3dKWUVVc5LEC51axDtXUL1uJf4oJCwCMiMUFCn1LRYyfTsMMjcTKwcHgxHI9OLqTQ6PQGIymcyWay2WKudyglTg7xYfyBYKhAERKIxRwqaSgpyJGr4QikchvOgMMZAwQpA7KRTKf7hIE4UF9CbZJB5ArQmZzXbVNwgLB-Bl8FY89L8MbDUZ4vlTEU7BaiSbISVyDmA2UNUGavZOA4SqUGriyi5XfBrel4pBQAAWaAMdgQiBgFCQkXYFFd1gA5v6dKKtSAXSAiLq8YN8NTKDQ6dbGUIWXJcEowV5IULDCYzDp4TY7I5kR50QWsUFgCEGQHCXFZGSjkmyCnaPRrWqZCWANbANAAd2AMyEvIOAsL4g18zNR2NvQVSpGY370xKpsWOrlhF3+x1Heu8HefrUs6d4X4N44-EK84UQA)